# How does a division function from a math library take care of precision error, which the division operator fails to do?

Tags: algorithm, math, floating-point, precision

While dividing two floating point values I was getting an incorrect answer due to precision error.  For example, 1001.05 / 5.0 should have been equal to 200.21 , but I got 200.2099999999.

The correcto result was obtained using a division function from our math library in stead of the '/'.  So what extra stuff is this library function doing to correct precision error? You could explain, or point me to information about standard algorithms that are used to correct precision error, which this function must have been using.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to tell us things like what language you are using, and what library you are talking about?

Answer (score 6):

Your math library is not using floats, or is rounding the result when you print it out.  200.21 cannot be precisely represented with standard floating point numbers.

Comment: +1. It is not as much that the divide is wrong, but that neither 200.21 or 1001.05 are exactly representable as floats in an IEEE form. Since the output is often rounded, many people just don't know there is floating point trash hanging around all the time.